# PHP: pcntl_fork() on the OSX command line

Tags: php, macos, command-line-interface, pcntl

I have a Macbook Pro running OSX Yosemite. I am trying to run a simple PHP script using `pcntl_fork()` on the command line (command: `php pcntl.php`):

```
<?php
    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    switch($pid) {
        case -1:
            print "Could not fork!\n";
            exit;
        case 0:
            print "In child!\n";
            break;
        default:
            print "In parent!\n";
    }
?>
```

The response is this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function pcntl_fork() in
>   /Users/grant/Desktop/test/pcntl.php on line 2

I've seen numerous articles that show you how to install pcntl if you are running mamp, but if you are simply using terminal, how would you go about installing pcntl? If this is not possible on the command line, is there something similar in PHP that does work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case of native CLI you should proceed the same way as in case of `MAMP`. The only difference is that you should add support to native `php` and not to `MAMP`'s one.

`Yosemite`'s php doesn't have `pcntl` support. Following command returns no output:

```
$ php -i | grep pcntl
```

Verify your php version:

```
$ php -v
  PHP 5.5.20 (cli) (built: Feb 25 2015 23:30:53)
```

Download and build `pcntl` module:

```
$ wget http://php.net/distributions/php-5.5.20.tar.xz
$ tar xf php-5.5.20.tar.xz
$ cd php-5.5.20
$ cd ext/pcntl/
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Copy module to extensions folder:

```
$ sudo cp modules/pcntl.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/
```

Edit `php.ini` configuration file:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/php.ini
```

And add `extension=pcntl.so` line in `Dynamic Extensions` section, e.g.:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
; If you only provide the name of the extension, PHP will look for it in its
; default extension directory.

extension=pcntl.so
```

Verify `pcntl` support again (support enabled this time):

```
$ php -i | grep pcntl
  pcntl
  pcntl support => enabled
```

Running your test script:

```
$ php -f test.php
  In parent!
  In child!
```

Comment: Great this can be extend also for other module ;).. nice one